# How to face the Turret Gun of my Tank to the direction of the Main Camera in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, rotation

Hello I want to Make the gun of my turret face the direction my camera is facing at.
I don't really know Complex Maths so can you keep it simple. Thanks

My code is this:

```
gun.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(tankCamera.eulerAngles.x - transform.eulerAngles.x, 0);
```

Here is the Complete Class:

```
public class TurretController : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
public Transform turret;
public Transform gun;
public Transform tankCamera;

[Header("Values")] 
public float lowestX = 23;
public float highestX = -9;
public float turnSpeed = 10f;
public float additionalX = 90f;
public float maxRadians = 90f;
public bool gunLocal = true;
public bool turretRotation = false;
public LayerMask layerMaskOfGun;

[Header("Read-Only")] [SerializeField] private Vector3 angle;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (turretRotation)
    {
        turret.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(turret.localRotation,
            new Quaternion(0, tankCamera.rotation.y, 0, turret.localRotation.w),
            Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
    }
    else
    {
        angle = new Vector3(0, (tankCamera.eulerAngles.y - transform.eulerAngles.y));
        //turret.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(turret.localEulerAngles, angle, Time.deltaTime / turnSpeed);
        turret.localEulerAngles = angle;
    }

    //if (gun.localRotation.x <= lowestX || gun.localRotation.x >= highestX)
    {
        if (gunLocal)
        {
            gun.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(tankCamera.eulerAngles.x - transform.eulerAngles.x, 0);
            //gun.localRotation = new Quaternion(tankCamera.rotation.x, 0f, 0f, gun.rotation.w);
        }
        else
        {
            Camera camera;
            //RaycastHit hit;
            //if (Physics.Raycast(tankCamera.position, tankCamera.forward, out hit, -layerMaskOfGun))
            {
                //gun.LookAt(hit.point);
                gun.LookAt(tankCamera.forward);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Why not use something like `Transform.LookAt`?https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html
Rotates the transform so the forward vector points at /target/'s current position.

Comment: but how? what's the code?

Comment: I can help you craft an answer but your code is not full or complete. How is this really being used? Please provide more code for me to help.

Comment: I'll edit the code above

Comment: I think you failed in building Quaternion from x y z w. You should not do that unless you know what are you doing.                                                                                       


new Quaternion(0, tankCamera.rotation.y, 0, turret.localRotation.w)